# SELinux prevents running command when using systemd on Fedora 25

Tags: systemd, selinux

I'm trying to run OpenVPN on a network namespace `myns` through systemd on Fedora 25. It looks like SELinux is preventing it from working.

Looking at `journalctl -xe`, I think this is the relevant part:

```
-- Subject: Unit myvpn.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit myvpn.service has begun starting up.
Jul 11 16:26:19 castiel audit[32456]: AVC avc:  denied  { mounton } for  pid=32456 comm="ip" path="/etc/resolv.conf" dev="sda1" ino=1572869 scontext=system_u:system_r:ifconfig_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:o
bject_r:net_conf_t:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
Jul 11 16:26:19 castiel audit[32456]: AVC avc:  denied  { execute } for  pid=32456 comm="ip" name="openvpn" dev="sda1" ino=1705174 scontext=system_u:system_r:ifconfig_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:o
penvpn_exec_t:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
Jul 11 16:26:19 castiel ip[32456]: Bind /etc/netns/myns/resolv.conf -> /etc/resolv.conf failed: Permission denied
Jul 11 16:26:19 castiel ip[32456]: exec of "/sbin/openvpn" failed: Permission denied
Jul 11 16:26:19 castiel systemd[1]: myvpn.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jul 11 16:26:19 castiel audit[1]: SERVICE_START pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=nordvpn comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? a
ddr=? terminal=? res=failed'
Jul 11 16:26:19 castiel systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenVPN connection to myvpn.
-- Subject: Unit myvpn.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit myvpn.service has failed.
```

---

`/var/log/audit/audit.log`:

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1499799030.259:16264): avc:  denied  { mounton }
    for  pid=1419 comm="ip" path="/etc/resolv.conf" dev="sda1" ino=1572869
    scontext=system_u:system_r:ifconfig_t:s0
    tcontext=system_u:object_r:net_conf_t:s0
    tclass=file permissive=0
type=AVC msg=audit(1499799030.259:16265): avc:  denied  { execute }
    for  pid=1419 comm="ip" name="openvpn" dev="sda1" ino=1705174
    scontext=system_u:system_r:ifconfig_t:s0
    tcontext=system_u:object_r:openvpn_exec_t:s0
    tclass=file permissive=0
type=SERVICE_START msg=audit(1499799030.268:16266):
    pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295
    subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=myvpn
    comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd"
    hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=failed'
type=SERVICE_START msg=audit(1499800402.528:16267):
    pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 
    subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=dnf-makecache comm="systemd" 
    exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
type=SERVICE_STOP msg=audit(1499800402.528:16268): 
    pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 
    subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=dnf-makecache comm="systemd" 
    exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
```

---

`# ll -Z /etc/resolv.conf` shows this:
`-rw-r--r--. 1 root root system_u:object_r:net_conf_t:s0 61 Jul  9 17:26 /etc/resolv.conf`

---

This is what the service file looks like:

```
[Unit]
[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/sbin/ip netns exec myns /sbin/openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/profiles/myprofile.ovpn --auth-user-pass /etc/openvpn/credentials --daemon openvpn@myprofile.ovpn --writepid /run/openvpn@myprofile.ovpn.pid
PIDFile=/run/openvpn@myprofile.ovpn.pid

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

If I set selinux to permissive (`setenforce 0`) it works fine.

---

If I run the command my self it works fine with selinux enforcing:

`/sbin/ip netns exec myns /sbin/openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/profiles/myprofile.ovpn --auth-user-pass /etc/openvpn/credentials --daemon openvpn@myprofile.ovpn --writepid /run/openvpn@myprofile.ovpn.pid`

`curl ifconfig.io` returns my public IP and
`ip netns exec myns curl ifconfig.io` returns the IP of the VPN server.

---

What must I do to make SELinux allow the systemd script to work without disabling SELinux altogether?

Comment: `audit2allow` after running with `setenforce 0`, or setup the netns in systemd instead (but it will not be a "named" netns as used by `ip netns`) https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/2741#issuecomment-273745146

Comment: If you're curious about why you can run the command yourself - it's because normal user logins are simply `unconfined` by default.  (See `id -Z`).  A third alternative is to transition to unconfined for this service.  Amusingly (to me) all you have to do is move your ExecStart command into a shell script, somewhere in a system directory like `/usr/` or `/etc/`, and run the script instead.  E.g. if a service is set as running a script which has defaulted to `bin_t` (see `ls -Z` after creation), it will transition to `unconfined`.

Comment: Hopefully `net_conf_t` is trying to transition to `openvpn_t`, and the `audit2allow` rules would just 1) let it do that, after 2) allowing the bind mount.  I guess that's not exactly perfect for `net_conf_t`, but it avoids opening things up completely.

Answer (score 2):

Running with `setenforce 0` I was able to get the following allow rules using `audit2allow`:

```
#============= ifconfig_t ==============
allow ifconfig_t net_conf_t:file mounton;
allow ifconfig_t openvpn_etc_t:file { getattr open read };
allow ifconfig_t openvpn_exec_t:file { execute execute_no_trans open read };
allow ifconfig_t openvpn_tmp_t:dir { read write };
```

I also got this rule from the same logs

```
#============= ifconfig_t ==============

#!!!! WARNING: 'tmp_t' is a base type.
allow ifconfig_t tmp_t:dir { read write };
```

To not have to allow this, I created a subfolder with the `openvpn_tmp_t` label under `/tmp` and ran `openvpn` 
with the `--tmp-dir` argument pointing to that directory.

---

After this I was still unable to start the service. Looking at `journalctl -xe`, I saw that there was a problem loading a configuration file:

```
-- Unit myvpn.service has begun starting up.
Jul 17 06:19:56 castiel ip[22825]: Options error: In [CMD-LINE]:1: Error opening configuration file: /etc/openvpn/profiles/myprofile.ovpn
Jul 17 06:19:56 castiel ip[22825]: Use --help for more information.
Jul 17 06:19:56 castiel systemd[1]: myvpn.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jul 17 06:19:56 castiel systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenVPN connection to myprofile.ovpn.
```

I tried again with `setenforce 0` and it was able to start up. Surprisingly there was *nothing* in the audit log about this.

I searched and came accross an [old question on Fedora selinux mailing list](https://lists.fedoraproject.org/pipermail/selinux/2010-November/013193.html). 
Apparently there is a `dontaudit` rule that blocks some messages from being logged.
This could be turned off with `semodule -DB` (re-enabled with `semodule -B`).

With the rest of the errors logged, I got some more rows that I turned in to rules with `audit2allow`:

```
#============= ifconfig_t ==============
allow ifconfig_t openvpn_etc_t:dir search;
allow ifconfig_t openvpn_tmp_t:dir search;

#============= init_t ==============
allow init_t ifconfig_t:process noatsecure;
allow init_t kernel_t:unix_stream_socket { read write };
```

With these policies combined I was able to get openvpn running inside of the network namespace through systemd.

I'm still not sure how secure these rules are or if there is a better way to go about this.